# higher-order functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have written the following code:

```
hosum :: (Int->Int)->(Int->Int)     
hosum f 0 = 1
hosum f n = afunction f (-abs(n)) (abs(n))


afunction :: (Int->Int)->Int->Int->Int
afunction f a z
    |a==z
        = 0
    |otherwise
        = afunction f (a+1) z + afunction f a z
```

to find the sum of f(i) from -|n| to |n|..  Where is my mistake?

Comment: You never call `f`.  Try deleting the type signatures and see what type GHC infers for your functions (the `f` argument will be completely polymorphic).

Comment: as @jcast said: you just need a summand more for your `otherwise` case but while manual recursion is nice to start I would recommend to think about how to do this with `map` and `sum` instead - **PS** what is the `hosum` for? I thnk you can just delete this here - also you might try to find better function names and give an example of how you want to call your functions - it's a bit strange here

Comment: @jcast i don't understand what you are saying just because i am a beginner with haskell .. this exercise is for my class  and my professor has told us to make this function starting with the following:    hosum :: (Int->Int)->(Int->Int)     hosum f n . something more clear would be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your code never calls the `f` function. There are several other things in your code that I don't understand:

1. `hosum f 0 = 1`. Why is it one for any `f`. Shouldn't it be `f 0`?
2. In `afunction`, why is the result `0` if `a == z`. If the range is inclusive, it should be zero only if `a > z`.
3. `afunction` in the `otherwise` case calls itself twice. Why doesn't it apply `f` to  `a` and calls `afunction f (a + 1) z` only?

Now about a correct solution.
The easiest(and idiomatic) way to implement it is to use standard `sum` and `map` functions. It gives a one-liner(if we don't count type signature):

```
hosum :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
hosum f n = sum $ map f [-abs(n)..abs(n)]
```

In plain English, this function takes a list of all numbers from `-abs(n)` to `abs(n)`, applies `f` to each of them and sums them up. That's exactly what the problem statement tells us to do.

Comment: Furthermore, what would i do, if i had  a list with function and one other list to make a new list where each element of the one list, map with the other element of the other list ? For example, apply [(^2),(^3),(^4),(2^)] [10] = 
[100,1000,1024,10000]. the length of each list could be bigger

Comment: @ΔιονυσιαΑγαλιώτη You can use list comprehensions. Something like this: `[f x | f <- [(2*), (2+)], x <- [1, 2]]` = `[2, 4, 3, 4]`.